# Core Data syncable & com.apple.syncservices.Syncable

Tags: ios, core-data, mobileme

Xcode sets `syncable="YES"` by default for entities & properties, e.g.,

```
$ cat AppName/AppName.xcdatamodeld/AppName.xcdatamodel/contents
...
<entity name="Event" representedClassName="Event" syncable="YES">
    <attribute name="timestamp" attributeType="Date" syncable="YES"/>
</entity>
...
```

Should I set `syncable` to `NO`? (I know I can do so by deleting `syncable="YES"` from the `contents` file or by adding the key-value pair `{com.apple.syncservices.Syncable, NO}` under the User Info section of the Data Model inspector.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, set `syncable` to `NO` because MobileMe syncing support is deprecated. See "Editing Core Data Models" of the [Xcode 4.4 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/RN-Xcode-Archive/Chapters/xc4_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016994-CH3-SW145):

> **Editing Core Data Models**
>
> - MobileMe syncing support is deprecated. However, the syncable property is still set to YES by default in the User Info Dictionary for entities and properties, but the model editor doesn’t show this setting. 10787672
>
> To explicitly set syncable to NO for an entity or a property, add a key/value pair in your User Info Dictionary:
>
> 1. Select the entity or property for which you want to turn off synching on a model file.
> 2. In the User Info section in the Data Model inspector, add this key/value pair:
>
>    - key   -  "com.apple.syncservices.Syncable"
>    - value   -  "No"